# How can i get weekday from another location in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timezone, location, weekday

I am in Vietnam, and I want to get the weekday in Finland today using Javascript.

> timeZone: 'Europe/Helsinki'

Do you have a good solution?

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you mean *which* day of the week it is in Europe/Helsinki time zone? As it may be only Monday when it’s already Tuesday in Vietnam. Or do you mean what the day of the week is called in Finnish or Swedish, the two languages spoken officially in Finland? Or both?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

> const weekday = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { weekday: 'long', timeZone: 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh' });

Comment: In what way, in what sense does this give us the day of week in Finland as opposed to that of some other location? I expect it to give the name in English (which, admitted, a lot of people in Finland will understand) of the day of week in Vietnam (currently 7 hours ahead of UTC).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) and specify the arguments you desire.

This will give you the full name in English of the current weekday in Finland:

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en', {
  timeZone: 'Europe/Helsinki',
  weekday: 'long'
}))
```